# Browser become irresponsive when more than 50000 records bind with datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, datatable

I have created an application in which I have used datatables and handler for binding data with datatable where I have used JSON dataformat.

When I request for the data First time all 100,000 records come in the datatable which is client side but when I click second time at datatable creation it will not execute the further code and browser become irresponsive and hanged.

```
var result1 = new { aaData = lst.Select(p => new[] { 
            p.SampleNumber, 
            p.CustomerCode, 
            p.CustomerName, 
            p.VerticalName})};
```

where there are more 10-15 columns in the list

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer 
{ 
    MaxJsonLength = 99999999, 
    RecursionLimit = 100 
};
var json = serializer.Serialize(result1);
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"; 
context.Response.Write(json);
```

like this i have binded the data with json

Comment: You're adding 50,000 records to a table and wondering why it's slow...? Change your handler to return a page of data at a time.

Comment: @roryMacrossan :  - Please clarify what type of changes i have to make in handler

Comment: No one can tell you that without seeing any of your server-side code, but I doubt it will be a simple change.

Comment: There is no possible use case for a user interaction that requires displaying 50000 records in a single page.

Comment: var result1 = new
                  {                        
                        aaData = lst
                            .Select(p => new[] {    p.SampleNumber                                  
                                                  , p.CustomerCode
                                                  , p.CustomerName
                                                  , p.VerticalName
                           })  where there are more column 10-15 in the list

Comment: };
                  var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer { MaxJsonLength = 99999999, RecursionLimit = 100 };
                  var json = serializer.Serialize(result1);
                  context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                  context.Response.Write(json);
                 
            }  and like this i have bind the data with json

Comment: @Rory McCrossan  :-- I have pasted my server side handler code with above two comments. Kindly help me in this.

Comment: Please use the edit feature and add it to your question so it's at least partly readable.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan --- i Have edited my question..

Comment: Thanks for your precious time. I got the answer. I am clearing the table data at every find click by using fncleartable().

Answer (score 1):

Browsers don't "like" to handle large data sets. They are not designed for this. People are the same. Suppose Wikipedia returned you 50k articles in 1 request. Would you be able to understand anything?

Return 10 (or 100) records that matter to the users and allow them to get the next page.

Comment: :-- In datatable i am getting more than 50,000 records but i have used paging in that where i am showing only 10 records per page. so i have more than 5000 pages in the datatable with the data.

Comment: Correct. Google stores petabates but only shows you 10 records at a time. You don't store pages in a database per se. You store all the data you have there, but only present small number at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time. I got the answer. I am clearing the table data at every find click by using fncleartable().